# How to cache http requests in async style in angular http inteceptor?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, operators, observable

I'm coding the angular 5 app. There is `refreshAccessToken` in `authentication service`

```
refreshAccessToken(): Observable<ICredentials> {
     const refreshTokenUrl = this.urlsService.getUrl(Urls.TOKEN);
     const httpParams = new HttpParams()
       .append('grant_type', 'refresh_token')
       .append('refresh_token', this.credentials.refresh_token)
       .append('client_id', Constants.CLIENT_ID)
       .toString();

     const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

     return this.http.post(refreshTokenUrl, httpParams, { headers })
       .map((response: any) => {
         this.setCredentials(response);
         localStorage.setItem(credentialsKey, JSON.stringify(this.getCredentials()));
         return response;
  });
}
```

I want to implement next alghorithm:

1. Any http request failed because of unauthorized with status 401
2. Try to get new access token from server
3. Repeat the request

At the time while getting new access token, new http requests can be created, in this case I want to store them and repeat after new access token was recieved. To reach this purpose I've written the interceptor.

```
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from '@app/core/authentication/authentication.service';
import { Urls, UrlsService } from '@app/shared/urls';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class UnauthorizedRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  newAccessToken$: Observable<ICredentials> = null;

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router,
    private urlsService: UrlsService) {
  }

  addAuthHeader(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
    if (this.authService.getCredentials()) {
      return request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authService.getCredentials().access_token
        }
      });
    }
    return request;
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = this.addAuthHeader(request);

    return next.handle(request).catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      let handleRequests$ = null;

      if (this.isNeedNewAccessToken(error, request)) {
        handleRequests$ = this.handleRequestWithNewAccessToken(request, next);
      }

      return handleRequests$ ||
        (this.isUnathorizedError(error)
          ? Observable.empty()
          : Observable.throw(error));
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }

  private isNeedNewAccessToken(error: HttpErrorResponse, request: HttpRequest<any>): boolean {
    return this.isUnathorizedError(error)
      && this.authService.isAuthenticated()
      && this.isSignInRequest(request);
  }

  private getNewAccessToken(): Observable<ICredentials> {
    if (!this.newAccessToken$) {
      this.newAccessToken$ = this.authService.refreshAccessToken();
    }
    return this.newAccessToken$;
  }

  private isUnathorizedError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return error.status === 401;
  }

  private handleRequestWithNewAccessToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    return this.getNewAccessToken()
      .mergeMap(() => {
        request = this.addAuthHeader(request);
        return next.handle(request);
      })
      .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error.error === 'invalid_grant') {
          this.logout();
        }
        return Observable.empty();
      });
  }

  private isNotSignInRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>): boolean {
    return request.url !== this.urlsService.getUrl(Urls.TOKEN);
  }
}
```

The behaviour of this interceptor is really strange. On each `mergeMap` on the `handleRequestWithNewAccessToken`the angular starts new post httpRequest. I've expected that the observable returned from `refreshAccessToken`(function from `authenticationService`, code at the top) would be resolved only once. I don't understand why it is fired for each merge map? I expected the next:

1. I have observable - http request for token
2. I use mergeMap - when http request finished, all callbacks that was added with mergeMap will be executed.

I was think to store requests that I need to handle in the global variable and invoke them in the `subscribe()` to http request, but there is problem, that each request should be resolved in the initial stream inside interceptor. I can't do smth like this: `.subscribe(token => this.httpClient.request(storedRequest)` because this will create new request, so all actions should be happened inside the observable chain.

Can you please help me to find solution?

**PS** This solution is working, but I want to get rid off unnecessary TOKEN requests, f.e. if page need to make 5 requests and token have expired - interceptor will make 5 requests for token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is good and all you have to do is `share` the request for the new token.

```
refreshAccessToken(): Observable<ICredentials> {
        const refreshTokenUrl = this.urlsService.getUrl(Urls.TOKEN);
        const httpParams = new HttpParams()
            .append('grant_type', 'refresh_token')
            .append('refresh_token', this.credentials.refresh_token)
            .append('client_id', Constants.CLIENT_ID)
            .toString();

        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        return this.http.post(refreshTokenUrl, httpParams, { headers })
            .map((response: any) => {
                this.setCredentials(response);
                localStorage.setItem(credentialsKey, JSON.stringify(this.getCredentials()));
                return response;
            })
            .share(); // <- HERE
    }
```

Note `share` operator at the end of `return`

EDIT:

I also think you don't ever set back `this.newAccessToken$` to `null`. Maybe consider adding set to `null` to `finally` like this:

```
private getNewAccessToken(): Observable<ICredentials> {
    if (!this.newAccessToken$) {
        this.newAccessToken$ = this.authService.refreshAccessToken()
            .finally(() => {
                this.newAccessToken$ = null;
            });
    }
    return this.newAccessToken$;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `share` did the trick, I've added it inside `getNewAccessToken`:  `this.newAccessToken$ = this.authService.refreshAccessToken().share(); this.newAccessToken$.finally(() => this.newAccessToken$ = null)`. Also to enable `finally` I've added the import `import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';`